# How do I easily compare coefficients of two polynomials in MuPad

Tags: polynomials, mupad

How do I easily compare coefficients of two polynomials in MuPad?

Comment: If this is a bad way to share this code, let me know and I can modify/remove this post!

Comment: I don't know anything about mupad so I can't speak for the quality of the question, but I'd suggest copying your question from the title into the body, and removing the reference to "My answer below". Both your question and answer should be able to stand as two completely separate entities.

Comment: I've done this; thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which defines operators such as =s^1=; this operator compares the s^1 coefficient. Code should be pretty easy to modify.

```
eqcoeff := (x, i, a, b) -> coeff(a, x, i) = coeff(b, x, i):
for n from 0 to 6 do
    operator("=s^" . n . "=", fp::curry(eqcoeff, 3)(s)(n), Binary, 1):
end:

// for example:
4*s+3 =s^0= 4*s+7; // 3=7
4*s+3 =s^1= 4*s+7; // 4=4
```